# Error con ruta en plantilla Symfony y Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony2, template

Estoy intentando probar un formulario con Symfony con un código copiado de internet. Se trata de dos selects, provincia y ciudad, en el que los valores de Ciudad dependen de lo que se seleccione en Provincia, pero cuando cargo la pagina me marca el siguiente error:

**An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "province_ajax_call" as such route does not exist.") in NoxLogicDemoBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 38.**

El código es el siguiente:

```
{% block title %}Contact{% endblock%}

{% block body %}
    <header>
        <h1>Crear evento</h1>
    </header>

    <p>Want to contact symblog?</p>

     <form action="{{ path('NoxLogicDemoBundle_formu') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} class="evento">
        {{ form_errors(form) }}

        {{ form_row(form.name) }}
        {{ form_row(form.province) }}
        {{ form_row(form.city) }}


        {{ form_rest(form) }}

    </form>

    {% block javascripts %}

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () 
        {
            $('#account_type_province').change(function()
            {
               var val = $(this).val();
               $.ajax(
               {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{{ url('province_ajax_call') }}?province_id=" + val,
                    success: function(data) 
                    {
                        // Remove current options
                        $('#account_type_city').html('');
                        $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                            $('#account_type_city').append('<option value="' + v + '">' + k + '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

    {% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

Todo el codigo que estoy usando está copiado de una pagina que te explica como hacer selects dependientes en symfony: https://adayinthelifeof.nl/2014/03/19/dynamic-form-modification-in-symfony2/

Entiendo que el enlace no está registrado en el archivo routing y lo sustituyo por la ruta del formulario. De esta forma me va, pero el select de las ciudades siempre está vacío, por lo que sigue habiendo un fallo.

Comment: ¿Podrías [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/37239/edit) tu pregunta y agregar el `JSON` que recibes como respuesta de la llamada `ajax` a `[province_ajax_call]?province_id=[x]`? Donde `province_ajax_call` es la `URL` al `endpoint` y `x` un `ID` de una provincia que tenga ciudades

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ url('province_ajax_call') }}?province_id=" + val,
    success: function(data) 
    {
        // Remove current options
        $('#account_type_city').html('');
        $.each(data, function(k, v) {
            $('#account_type_city').append('<option value="' + v + '">' + k + '</option>');
        });
    }
});
return false;
```

Revisando esta parte en específico del código, si verificas, estás diciendole al AJAX que pase la información con POST y le estás mandando parámentros GET (`?province_id=" + val`); para resolver esto el ajax debe ser algo como esto

```
type: 'post'
data: {'province_id' : val}
url: "{{ path('province_ajax_call') }}
```

nótese que cambié `{{url(...)}}` por `{{path(..)}}` ya que esta es la forma actual de generar las rutas; por otro lado, lo recomendable es que guardes el generador de rutas en tu archivo de rutas  routing.yml (valga la redundancia), adjunto un ejemplo de en YML

```
nombre_de_la_ruta:
    path:     /algo/ajax/
    defaults: { _controller: NombreDelBundle:AccionEnControlador}
```

con esto, el path sería, en modo de ejemplo `{{path('nombre_de_la_ruta')}}`.

Luego, en el controlador

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
public function AccionEnControladorAction(){
  $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
  $provinceId = $request->request->get('province_id');
  //acciones que realizarás

  $response = new JsonResponse($retorno);
}
```

con esto estarás retornando los datos en formato json, que es el que corresponde para este ejemplo, finalmente en el `.success(data)` podrás manipular los datos de retorno.